# Wordpress Taxonomy listing - Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, function, templates, pagination

I found this excellent function to display all the posts listed under a specific custom taxonomy. It works great. Found here http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/wordpress-list-posts-by-taxonomy I tried a number of ideas, however unsuccessful, to try and paginate the returned data. I either get no data or it continues to display the entire list. Some of my taxonomies have over 10K posts associated. So pagination would seem logical.

What I want to do is; have the information that gets returned create pages of 'n' number of posts and make links for the other pages (1,2,...4,5 etc). Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tossed this in my functions file;

```
   function list_posts_by_taxonomy( $post_type, $taxonomy, $get_terms_args = array(),
   $wp_query_args = array() ){
   $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $get_terms_args );

    if( $tax_terms ){
    foreach( $tax_terms  as $tax_term ){
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            "$taxonomy" => $tax_term->slug,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
        );
        $query_args = wp_parse_args( $wp_query_args, $query_args );

        $my_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <h2 id="<?php echo $tax_term->slug; ?>" class="title">
            <?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></h2>

            <ul>
            <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

               <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" 
                    title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
}

?>
```

And this code goes in the template, stuff whatever 'taxonomy' name and it displays the data. Another questions I was not sure about, if the pagination should go in the function or the template.

```
<div class="my_class">
<?php
list_posts_by_taxonomy( 'my_posttype', 'taxo_mytaxo' );
?>
</div>
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have pagination with your query first of all you have to use the `paged` parameter.
To get some extra info check the wordpress codex for [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

Usually you get the pagination variable like this:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
```

Then you pass it to the query by including it in the query arguments for your code:

```
$query_args = array(
            'post_type'           => $post_type,
            "$taxonomy"           => $tax_term->slug,
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'      => -1,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
            'paged'               => $paged //I've added it here
        );
```

Then you'll have to build the pagination links something like(this will be done inside the loop):

```
<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```